# How to pass string array to AlertDialog builder.setItems()

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-alertdialog

I am using Alert Dialog builder in order to visualize the paired bluetooth devices. I want to pass a sstring array to the `setItems()` method in order to create the list with the devices. `setItems()` gets `CharSequence[]` and a listener. When i pass the string array it fails. How can i fix it? Here is the code:

```
public void showPairedDevices() {
    String[] pairedDevicesArray = new String[100];

    // Get a set of currently paired devices
    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevicesSet = bluetoothAdapter
            .getBondedDevices();

    if (pairedDevicesSet.size() > 0) {
        int i = 0;
        for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevicesSet) {
            pairedDevicesArray[i] = device.getName();
            i++;
        }

        connectDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        connectDialog.setTitle("Paired devices");
        connectDialog.setItems(pairedDevicesArray, connectDialogClickListener);
        connectDialog.show();

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "No paired devices!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
}

private OnClickListener connectDialogClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface connectDialog, int button) {
        connectDialog.dismiss();
    }
};
```

Comment: It's suppose to work.. whats the error that you get?

Comment: Are you sure its the array and not your click listener? Please post your logs.

Comment: The exception is NullPointerException, but what happens exactly? It fails when it reaches the connectDialog and the dialog isn't displayed, the listener is not a problem. Part of the log:

 E/AndroidRuntime(22953): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-29 18:27:10.542: E/AndroidRuntime(22953): java.lang.NullPointerException

When i comment out the line: connectDialog.setItems(pairedDevicesArray, connectDialogClickListener);

the program runs successfully and shows a dialog with a title only. So that line makes the problem. What could be the issue?

Comment: Also you should know that the above code works only if i define the items in the dialog like this:

String[] pairedDevicesArray = {"TRobot", "PC", "TDroid"};

But i want to get them from the system, not to declare them as constants.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue stems from the fact that you're starting with a `String` array that is too big.  When you initialize an array of objects, every space is by default `null`.  With that in mind, what you should know is that when you feed an array that is of length 100 to `setItem()`, it is going to check *every* index, and if it finds a `null` it will throw an error.  Here is a proposed solution:

```
public void showPairedDevices() {
    // Get a set of currently paired devices
    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevicesSet = bluetoothAdapter
            .getBondedDevices();

    if (pairedDevicesSet.size() > 0) {

        // This will set the size of the array to exactly how many you need
        String[] pairedDevicesArray = new String[pairdDevicesSet.size()];

        int i = 0;
        for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevicesSet) {
            pairedDevicesArray[i] = device.getName();
            i++;
        }

        // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrew! It works and now i understand the error. Many thanks!